# Python removing letters from a string?

Tags: python

Without using python's `re.sub`, how would I remove and print `ONLY` letters from a string with no spaces?

For example I want `("ABCD!@#(   EFGH@!(# IJ K912??")` to print out as `ABCDEFGHIJK`

Comment: What possible solutions have you tried, what approaches have you considered? Don't you want to do you homework yourself in order to learn something?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple approach:

```
s = "ABCD!@#( EFGH@!(# IJ K912??"
print "".join(c for c in s if c.isalpha())
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the string class. Do you want upper case only, lower case, or both? If upper, use string.ascii_uppercase, if lower, use string.ascii_lowercase, if both use string.ascii_letters. Example:

```
import string
temp = "ABCD!@#( EFGH@!(# IJ K912??"
print(''.join([t for t in temp if t in string.ascii_letters]))
```